# Dynamically generated Listbox with nested Grid

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, grid

I have this c# code where i read items from an xml file and arrange the images and titles in a ListBox. I also added a SelectionChanged event handler to the listbox to handle selection. However when I click any row in the ListBox, the publicationsList_SelectionChanged event handler tells me that the grid control is being selected not the listbox control. This does not allow me to use listbox's selectedItem property get and use the selected title and image to navigation to the next page. Please help.

```
// Deserialize if download succeeds
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Publications));
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
// get all the employees
Publications publications = (Publications)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());

Grid grid1 = new Grid();
// bind data to ListBox
ListBox listBox = new ListBox();

foreach (Publication pub in publications.itemsPublications)
{
   Grid grid = new Grid();
   Image itemImage = new Image();
   BitmapImage BitImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pub.imageurl, UriKind.Absolute)); 
   itemImage.Source = BitImg;

   itemImage.Width= 97;
   itemImage.Height = 125;

   Grid.SetRow(itemImage, 0);
   Grid.SetColumn(itemImage, 0);
   itemImage.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

   ColumnDefinition columnDefinition1 = new ColumnDefinition();
   ColumnDefinition columnDefinition2 = new ColumnDefinition();
   columnDefinition1.Width = new GridLength(100);
   columnDefinition2.Width = new GridLength(250);
   grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition1);
   grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition2);
   grid.Children.Add(itemImage);
   listBox.Items.Add(grid);

   StackPanel stackPanel1 = new StackPanel();
   TextBlock titleBlock = new TextBlock();
   titleBlock.Text = pub.title;
   stackPanel1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0);
   stackPanel1.Height = 60;
   stackPanel1.Children.Add(titleBlock);
   stackPanel1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
   grid.Children.Add(stackPanel1);
}

listBox.SelectionChanged += publicationsList_SelectionChanged;
PivotItem pvt = e.UserState as PivotItem;
grid1.Children.Add(listBox);
pvt.Content = grid1;


private void publicationsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var app = App.Current as App;
        // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox. 
        //app.selectedPublication = (Publication)(sender as Grid);
        MessageBox.Show(e.AddedItems[0].ToString());
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PublicationPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

[enter link description here](http://www.thegatekeepers.ng/screenshot1.png)
Publication Class

```
public class Publication
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("imageurl")]
    public string imageurl { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("price")]
    public string price { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("author")]
    public string author { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("itempages")]
    public string itempages { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("alias")]
    public string alias { get; set; }
}
```

Publications Class

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Publications
{
    [XmlArray("publications")]
    [XmlArrayItem("publication")]
    //        public ObservableCollection<Publication> Collection { get; set; }
    public Publication[] itemsPublications {get; set;}
}
```

[[1]: http://www.thegatekeepers.ng/screenshot1.png](http://www.thegatekeepers.ng/screenshot1.png)

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Use an `ItemsControl`. BTW, XAML already supports DataBinding to XML. You're reinventing the wheel, and you're making it square. Delete all your code and start all over.

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you need, and the full code of your `Publications` class and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF/XAML.

Comment: You tagged this as 2 similar, but often incompatible technologies. Which is it? WPF or Phone?

Comment: @WiredPrairie its Phone.

Comment: i have updated the post with a publication and publications class and also linked a screenshot sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean when you say *the publicationsListSelectionChanged event handler tells me that the grid control is being selected not the listbox control*, as that makes absolutely no sense at all. In order to access the `ListBox` in the `SelectionChanged` handler, you simply have to cast the `sender` input parameter to a `ListBox`. However, you don't even need to access the `ListBox` as you can just access the selected item directly from the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` object:

```
private void publicationsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the currently selected item from the ListBox
    ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
    Publication selectedItem = (Publication)listBox.SelectedItem;
    // Or you can just do this without the ListBox reference
    selectedItem = (Publication)e.AddedItems[0]);
    ...
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

I can't understand why your `listBox.SelectedItem` property is returning a `Grid`... although I can't see an obvious problem, you *must* have an error in your code somewhere. If you were writing your application as a WPF application instead of as a WinForm application as yo uare now, you probably wouldn't have these problems. You should read through the [`Introduction to WPF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN to find out how to do things correctly.

However, *if* your `listBox.SelectedItem` property *is* returning a `Grid`, then you can try a few things. First, see if your object has been set as the `Grid.DataContext`:

```
private void publicationsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
    Grid selectedGrid = (Grid)listBox.SelectedItem;
    Publication selectedItem = (Publication)selectedGrid.DataContext;
    ...
}
```

If that still doesn't get your data object, then put a break point on the third line and investigate what is inside the `Grid` and where the data item is.

Also, did you try the other method as well?:

```
private void publicationsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
    Publication selectedItem = (Publication)e.AddedItems[0]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i get an error on this line "Publication selectedItem = listBox.SelectedItem;" Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to FolktalesMoonlightMobile.Publication

Comment: Just try casting the `listBox.SelectedItem` object to a `Publication`... see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the changes. It now doesnt give an error in the code but at runtime. the error on this line Publication selectedItem = (Publication)listBox.SelectedItem; is now "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'FolktalesMoonlightMobile.Publication'." Thanks for the help so far.